# Sampling distribution of the sample mean

Tags: r, distribution, sample, sampling, mean

I have a simple question, although I cant find an answer anywhere. 
I have the following dataset:

```
data.set <- c(7,7,8,8,7,8,9)
```

The question from the Basic Stats book is: 
What is the sampling distribution of the sample mean for samples of size 2?
Is there a possibility to calculate this in R commander (or using command line).

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple of ways to look at the sampling distribution when doing a simple random sample without replacement:

```
# Exact
data.set <- c(7,7,8,8,7,8,9)
samps <- combn(data.set, 2)
xbars <- colMeans(samps)
table(xbars)
prop.table(table(xbars))
barplot(table(xbars))

# Simulated
data.set <- c(7,7,8,8,7,8,9)
out <- replicate( 10000, mean( sample(data.set, 2) ) )
prop.table(table(out))
hist(out)
```

The exact version works fine for small populations (like this one), but will not be practical for large populations/samples, e.g. if your population size is 100 and your samples are of size 10 and you can calculate 10,000 means per second it would still take almost 55 years to do the exact version, so the simulated version would be much better in that case.

Comment: Mr. Snow and Mr. Henry thank you really very much for your prompt responses. They are highly appreciated. Regards, Iris

Answer (score 1):

This

```
mean2 <- function(x,y){ (x+y)/2 }
table(outer(data.set, data.set, "mean2")) / length(data.set)^2
```

will give

```
         7        7.5          8        8.5          9 
0.18367347 0.36734694 0.30612245 0.12244898 0.02040816
```

which may be the kind of thing you are looking for.  The probabilities are 1/49 of 9,  18,  15,   6,   and 1.

---

Added: without replacement

```
mean2 <- function(x,y){ (x+y)/2 }
L     <- length(data.set)
table(outer(data.set, data.set, "mean2")[- ((L+1)*(1:L)-L) ] ) / (L*(L-1))
```

to give

```
        7       7.5         8       8.5 
0.1428571 0.4285714 0.2857143 0.1428571
```

which are 1/7, 4/7, 2/7, 1/7 respectively,

Comment: If you sample with replacment that is.

Comment: @IrisPriest If the book really gives as *the sampling distribution of the sample mean* just the number '21', the book is an abomination and you should kill it with fire.

Comment: @Glen_b I'm sorry for a confusing comment (deleted). Obviously, as a response, the book gives the actual sampling distribution. I just wanted to emphasize the idea that this is without replacement. Thanks, Iris